# WP_Query Class custom field parameters

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, meta-query

In the the `class WP_Query`, using the `meta_query(array)`.
The wordpress codex says that the `'value'` is a `string|array`. The `array` support is limited to a `compare` value of `'IN'`, `'NOT IN'`, `'BETWEEN'`, or `'NOT BETWEEN'`.

I am having trouble as to understanding the `'IN'`, `'NOT IN'`, or `'BETWEEN'` arguments.

Could someone please help me as to understanding this or better yet a working example i could go by. I'm trying to query posts on a single page template by `meta_key` without writing a seperate template for each `meta_value`. After some research the `query_posts` that I've been using is just not the way to go.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For the future: Please use proper Upper-/lowercase and the WYSIWG editor buttons. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, `IN`, `NOT IN`, or `BETWEEN` work essentially like the [MySQL operators of the same name](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html). They are just abstracted somewhat.

However, it sounds to me like you don't need to worry about that. Your description makes me think that you are only worried about the `meta_key` itself and not any particular `meta_value`s or range of values, which means you can just use a simple [`meta_key`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) argument (Look for "Simple Custom Field Query:")